# CodeIgniter Upload Library not returning file extension

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, upload

**For some reason Stack Overflow is removing this top line, I start by saying Hi and thank you for looking.**

Just as the title says Code Igniter isn't returning a files extension type. I have tried

```
$upload_data = $this->upload->data();

    $ext = $upload_data['file_ext'];
```

but it returns an empty string.

**If I var dump $upload_data I get, which as you can see has no file type. Is this a bug? Am I missing something? everything else works as intended except I can't retrieve the file extension in order to put it in the DB.**

```
array (size=14)
  'file_name' => string '123456' (length=6)
  'file_type' => string '' (length=0)
  'file_path' => string 'uploads/' (length=8)
  'full_path' => string 'uploads/123456' (length=14)
  'raw_name' => string '123456' (length=6)
  'orig_name' => string '' (length=0)
  'client_name' => string '' (length=0)
  'file_ext' => string '' (length=0)
  'file_size' => string '' (length=0)
  'is_image' => boolean false
  'image_width' => string '' (length=0)
  'image_height' => string '' (length=0)
  'image_type' => string '' (length=0)
  'image_size_str' => string '' (length=0)
```

File renaming :

```
     /altering file name to user input
        $str = $this->input->post('filename');
        $config['file_name'] = $str;
   //adding name to DB
    $imagename = $str;

    $this->Image_model->addImage($imagename, $imageurl);
```

To clarify my query, I want to be able to retrieve the file extension so I can store its URI(URL?) in the database so I can eventually populate a dropdown with images in the database already.

Comment: What is the real file name you've uploaded (including the extionsion)?

Comment: It gets renamed during upload to whatever the user enters, but to answer your question anyway "test.jpg" - The reason I don't believe this is a problem is because it doesn't remove the extension once it's placed in the upload folder, rather it has the new name AND its extension.

Comment: Does the user enter the full name of the file in the input? including file name and extension? I mean `$this->input->post('filename')`

Comment: No just the first part not the extension, does this overwrite it? I assumed this wasn't the problem because the folder the images are being uploaded to are named correctly and with the correct extension.

So if I start with image "test.jpg" and user uploads it and names it "notttest.jpg" it will be in my /uploads/ folder as nottest.jpg but the database entry will only show "nottest".

Comment: Yes, of course! that's the problem, CodeIgniter tries to rename the file according to the `file_name` config which should include the file extension as well.

Comment: Then I do not understand how you are supposed to be able to allow users to rename their files.

Comment: Ask the filename from the user, then append the file extension to the user's input which must be equal to the real file extension (and the extension in the file_name must also be an allowed file type)

Comment: If I comment out //$str = $this->input->post('filename');
  //$config['file_name'] = $str; - Then no name at all gets entered into the database. But the database values are pulled from   $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
  $imagename = $upload_data['file_name'];
  $imageurl = $upload_data['full_path'];
  $ext = $upload_data['file_ext'];

I'm even more confused now.

Comment: @Hashem Thank you, I have figured it out, a simple mistake, I'd simply tried calling uploaddata before the check to see if it was successful all values are now populating, thank you for your time! :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `pathinfo( $imagename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION )` to get extention of an file regardless of you using any lib.

example :

```
$link = 'base.mini.css';

if( pathinfo( $link, PATHINFO_EXTENSION ) == 'css' ){

echo "css file";

}else{

echo "file ext is :".pathinfo( $link, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );
}
```

yet please NOTE that in the example you provided the file name does not contain and extension ! so it is normal that codeigniter could not figure out the extension for that file !